# Disk space consumption issues after Mac OS upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, memory, virtualization

I recently upgraded to Mojove OS for my Macbook Air-2015 model(128G storage). After the upgrade I had 35GB of storage space marked as free in my Storage preferences.

As I use my system over the period of day the free storage shrinks. In an hour it shrinks up by 2-3 GB and after few hours I run into the infamous "Free up some space" popup and the storage space is now reduced to under 5GB.

I investigated and there are no hidden apps/content caching/cloud backups etc. In fact my diskutil shows that all this space is being used by the VM that my Mac OS is using for swap space. All my free memory is being gobbled up by the VM.

Also I must mention that I am not doing any heavy lifting with my Mac - no coding, no editing etc. All I use my Mac for is to read a few documents(mostly pdf that too with the default Preview app) and a few tabs on chrome(not more than 5 at a time). I use the web primarily for surfing or youtube and rarely download more than a couple of documents. Also i close all opened apps using Cmd+Q after finished using.

Now the way I have been dealing with this is to switch off my laptop and on reboot I immediately get all 35GB of free storage space back.
I want to understand what is going on and how can i deal with this situation better. More specifically,

1) Why is VM taking so much space which keeps on increasing despite very similar nature of usage throughout the day. (I get it why it must increase as I load more apps but it keeps increasing monotonically without any correlation to my usage)?

[[image: snapshot of diskutil[1]]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  One question per question, please. If you can use the edit function to get this down to one question that would be great. Or just narrow down and ask another single question  - [link to the url here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388849/5472). When you get an answer to the first question you can edit this to ask your second or follow on question and that will trigger a review to reopen this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please also add the result of `diskutil list`?

Comment: Also some detail about why you tagged the question with vmware might help. Are you running a VM on your Mac?

Comment: @nohillside I was able to fix it by identifying the process using up all this VM of my Mac. It was running as root and I dismissed it as a system process in initial diagnosis. It was a buggy daemon process with a weird name. I just removed it from 'launchd' list (responsible for running daemons) and things are fine now. I am still puzzled though about how this was caused by an OS update.